# how to re-install TWRP from Linux?

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader, htc, formatting

```
Android version:       4.4.3
HTC Sense version:     6.0
software number:       2.23.661.2
HTC SDK API level:     6.25

kernel version:        3.4.0-g52343b3
                       and @ABM105 #1
                       SMP PREEMPT
build version:         2.23.661.2.CL3568029 release-keys
```

Previously I was locked in a loop where only `TWRP` was available.  The developer option is certainly enabled.  At the moment, not sure how to get back to the `TWRP` menu.

How do I accomplish a fresh install of a new version of `TWRP`?  I was going to connect it with Linux.

TWRP says:

> How can I uninstall or remove TWRP from my device?
>
> For the vast majority of devices, you don't actually remove TWRP to
>   get back to the stock recovery. Installing a different recovery is
>   your only real option. Simply install whatever recovery that you want
>   and that will overwrite or replace TWRP. Usually you can follow the
>   instructions on our website for installing TWRP manually, only use the
>   file for whatever recovery you are choosing to install instead of the
>   TWRP file.
>
> Note, we don't keep or maintain a database of stock recoveries. If you
>   are trying to reinstall the stock recovery, you will have to find a
>   copy of the stock recovery on your own.

although I'm not entirely clear on what they mean by "another recovery", but, how do I actually install from Linux?

see also:

https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-twrp/
https://www.androidguru.eu/twrp-installation-tutorial-linux-mint-ubuntu-users/

basically, so long as I get the correct image it's quite simple?  Since it was already installed I don't need to muck with locked boot loaders??

[What does "fastboot oem lock" do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21460/48164)

Comment: [What is the difference between twrp-version-phone.img and twrp-installer-version-phone.zip?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220359)

Answer (score 1):

The quoted text is for "uninstalling" TWRP

If i understand your question correctly, your only concern is to update TWRP to newer version

before flashing new image it is recommended to test if it works without flashing (not all devices support this)

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

installing TWRP depends on device

some devices don't have recovery partition. in this case you need another self installing zip file which will install TWRP in recovery-ramdisk in boot partition

if device has separate recovery partition you can simply flash the partition image

this can be done from fastboot

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

from pc command line

```
adb push twrp.img /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery
```

or even from TWRP itself in Advanced - Terminal

```
cat /external_sd/twrp.img > /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery
```

Some TWRP variant does allow backup/restore recovery. in this case you can just rename the `twrp.img` into `recovery.emmc.win`, place it into empty backup folder `TWRP/BACKUPS/*/recovery` and restore backup

Note: Your bootloader must remain unlocked as long as TWRP (or any other modified partition) is installed. re-locking bootloader is only recommended after you flashed full stock ROM including stock recovery. Otherwise you will brick